# Vim is not properly indenting the first line of Python blocks

Tags: python, vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently installed Ubuntu in my Windows machine with WSL.  I have only used it to write some Python code and push that code to GitHub.

My problem is that at some point last night, Vim stopped autoindenting after starting e.g. a for loop.  If I indent one line and then hit Enter, the next line *is* indented.

If I type, for example, "for x in mylist:[Enter]print(x)," what I would see is

```
for x in mylist:
print(x)
```

rather than

```
for x in mylist:
  print(x)
```

My .vimrc is

```
set number
hi Comment ctermfg=White
set ai
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab
```

`:set ft?` returns `filetype=python`

`:filetype` returns `filetype detection:ON  plugin:OFF  indent:OFF`.

`filetype plugin indent on` does not fix my issue.

I hope I'm missing something here.  I've found a lot of people with similar questions, but the best answers I've seen just say how to check if certain settings are enabled, and not what to do if enabling those settings doesn't help.  Also, none of the questions seem to be quite the same as mine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation rules are processed upon receiving `FileType` event. Which, in turn, is fired upon `BufRead` event. Hence you must have `filetype indent on` before opening your file. Or manually re-apply the event with `:e` or `:setf python` or whatever else.

Comment: Great, thank you!  That gives me an 8-space indent; do I need to change ```tabstop``` to fix that?

Comment: @PeterOhaver Make sure you have `filetype plugin on` (also before opening a file). It is `ftplugin` responsible for settng options such as `tabstop`, `shiftwidth` etc.